# My splash screen image always gets some rounded white corners

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've tried adding and substracting a lot of stuff but whenever my splash screen gets launched there is always a round corner or a type of elevation in the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3c3734"
tools:context="com.example.akshay.athleticgo.SplashScreen">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#3c3734"
    android:src="@mipmap/ath_splash"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my style am using

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

[image: this is the image]

Comment: As you are using image from mipmap and mipmap is only for launcher icons. Most of the cases Launcher icon has gradient border/shadow. I think your image has this gradient border. Check your image first.

Comment: no the image is a simple png image without any border.
If mipamp is only for icons then where should i place the image for splash screen?

Comment: In drawable folder. Path: /res/drawable/ath_splash.png

Comment: @FerdousAhamed thanks a lot it worked :D

Comment: Good to know that. I have added this as answer. Hope you can mark it as right answer and also vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using image from `mipmap` folder and `mipmap` is only for `launcher` icons. Most of the cases launcher icon has gradient `border/shadow`. I think your image has this `gradient` border. Check your image first.

Best practice is to put `image` resource files into `drawable` folder and use(`android:src="@drawable/ath_splash"`) it into `views` as per your needs.